# Running ReactJS app on prod with pm2 and https

Tags: reactjs, pm2

I am trying to host my reactJS app on pm2 but can't get the parameters right.

Firstly, the below works perfect.

`serve -s build --listen 8060 --ssl-cert "/cert/path.pem" --ssl-key "/key/path/key.pem"`

And we get

"serving, https://localhost:8060"

Now, how do we call serve with those parameters with pm2

Tried a lot of combinations of passing the params like the one below, and many more based on googled answers here and elsewhere. Nothing does what is expected

```
pm2 start --name front "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=/cert/path.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=/key/path/key.pem" serve -s build
```

**update:**
I could get this working with development server for now.

`PORT=8060 HTTPS=true pm2 start --name front npm -- run start:prod`

But, it would of course be nice if we could use a production optimized server.